# printing out a list of string using a for loop and a specified format

Tags: java

so i am supposed to print out a list of string in this format. 2017/2018 , 2018/2019, 2019/2020 up until 2029/2030 in this same format, please i am stuck and have no idea how to go about it.

```
  public List<String> getSessions() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    String firstHalf = "2017";
    String otherHalf = "2018";
    List<String> session = new ArrayList<>();

   for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
     a = Integer.parseInt(firstHalf) + 1;
     sb.append(a);
     sb.append("/");
     for(int j = i; j < 13; j++) {
       b = Integer.parseInt(otherHalf) + 1;
       sb.append(b);
     }
     session.add(sb.toString());
   }
   System.out.println(session);
   return session;
  }
```

however it doesn't do the needed, please help me out. thanks

Comment: Why should it be strings?

Comment: that's the requirement

Comment: How do you expect to increment a String value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but you can use this to print out values :

```
List<String> session = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 2017; i < 2030; i++) {
    session.add(i + "/" + (i + 1) + "\n");
}
System.out.println(session);
```

You don't need to use a nested loop or even a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need two `for loops`. Instead you can do following:

```
public List<String> getSessions() {
   int a = 2017;
   int b = 2018;
   List<String> session = new ArrayList<>();
   while (b <= 2030) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(a);
      sb.append("/");
      sb.append(b);
      session.add(sb.toString());
      a++;
      b++;
   }
   System.out.println(session);
   return session;
}
```

Comment: @Nicholas K, I make changes in poster's (@olatunji oniyide) code. So that he can understand it in easier way :). Thanks !!